# setTextAlignment() doesn't work when editing data

Tags: qt4, qstandarditemmodel

I use `QStandardItem::setTextAlignment()` to make sure elements displayed in center, but when you double click on a item, aka editing mode, it is still displayed at the left most position.

So, how can I make editing mode work as display mode?

Answer (score 1):

It seems more a problem with the delegate than with the QStandardItem.

Editing a QString, the [default delegate editor factory](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qitemeditorfactory.html) returns a [QLineEdit](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html).

Afaik, that is the default behaviour of a QLineEdit and if you want to change it you will have to create your own lineedit class and your own delegate.